# Best dimensionality reduction algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, svm

What is the best dimensionality reduction algorithm and what are the selection criteria we can use? I know PCA is the best technique when it comes to mean-square and linear reduction.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no best technique**, period. It applies to all unsupervised learning, where there is no actual aim/criterion different than the one **inside** the method. This is why for classification you have better and worse methods, but you do not have better/worse clusterers and/or dimensionality reduction. You only have **different** ones, doing different things, thats all.

Each method is best in what it does. PCA is best for linear reduction leading to highest preserved variance, because it is its definition, not because it is better than other doing the same - there are no others doing the same.

I deliberately omit problems with non-converging methods, there you can obviously say that some optimization technique (algorithm) is better than the other. But it is important to make a distinction between method (such as PCA) and a particular solver/implementation (such as SVD, randomized PCA, etc.)

Listing all dimensionality reduction techniques with their definitions (as this is what they are "best at") is beyond the scope of SO, in particular because there are dozens (hundreads) of them and you can easily find them by googling.